# Unity3d - Immediately force transition without waiting until current animation ends

Tags: unity, animation, animation-states

I created a animation Controller and attached it to the Animator component of my main camera. My Animation Controller looks like this:

[image: Animation Controller]

I am building a Main Menue. If the user presses on the buttons, then the camera is animated to different places in the world.

Each transition is linked with a condition, e.g. the Transition going from `CameraIdle` to `ToLoadscreen` has a condition called `GoToLoadscreen` which is a boolean parameter, the camera is only getting animated to the Loadscreen, if its value is true.

However, the transition is only starting after the current animation `CameraIdle` finished playing, as you can see in the next picture, `CameraIdle` is still getting played even though the parameter `GoToLoadscreen` is set to true.

[image: Animation Controller 2]

How can I force the transition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can force the transition to immediately happen, by clicking on the transition and unchecking `Has Exit Time`.

[image: Has Exit Time]

Now the transition is immediately forced and you don't have to wait until the current animation `CameraIdle` is finished.

Comment: This helps, but still there are some frames present, the transition is not instant